# Matlab image normalization after filtering

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, normalization

I have the following code, which I am trying to normalize my images after filtering but the problem is that as soon as it get to line 5, it change everyting to 0 and it returns me black images. any idea ?

```
 for i=1:10     
     temp_imag = imag_test1{i}(:,:);
     t_max = max(max(temp_imag));
     t_min = min(min(temp_imag));
     temp_imag = (temp_imag-t_min).*double(((new_max-new_min)/(t_max-t_min)))+double(new_min);
     imag_test1{i}(:,:) = temp_imag;
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't tell which values `new_max` and `new_min` get, but anyway if every after line 5 (`temp_imag = (temp_imag-t_min).*double(((new_max-new_min)/(t_max-t_min)))+double(new_min);`
) everything becomes zero, there are a few possibilities:

1. `imga_test{i}` (`1 <= i <= 10`) are all zeros and `new_min` is also zero. Have you checked the value of `imga_test` that they are not all zeros and that they vary? You can create example data for `imga_test` eg. by using `rand` or `randi`. If random data gives you non-zeros, the problem is in `imga_test`.
2. `new_max-new_min` is zero, which means that `new_max` and `new_min` have same value. Have you tried changing values for `new_max` and `new_min` and changing their difference? If changing the values of `new_max`, `new_min` or both gives you non-zeros, the problem is in `new_max` and `new_min`.
3. By using `solve` to solve the equation eg. for `new_min`:

   `solve('temp_imag = (temp_imag-t_min)*(((new_max-new_min)/(t_max-t_min)))+(new_min)', 'new_min')`:

   `ans =
   (new_max*t_min - new_max*temp_imag - t_min*temp_imag + t_max*temp_imag)/(t_max - temp_imag)`

This third case is very improbable.

Answer (score 1):

I would try presenting the pre v.s. post processed image:

```
figure();
for i=1:10     
     temp_imag = imag_test1{i}(:,:);
     subplot( 1, 2, 1 ); imshow( temp_imag, [] ); title( 'pre' ); 
     t_max = max(max(temp_imag));
     t_min = min(min(temp_imag));
     temp_imag = (temp_imag-t_min).*double(((new_max-new_min)/(t_max-t_min)))+double(new_min);
     subplot( 1, 2, 2 ); imshow( temp_imag, [] );  title( 'post' );    
     imag_test1{i}(:,:) = temp_imag;
 end
```